# Is there a geometric proof of this geometric interpretation of the Vandermonde determinant formula?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, determinant, area

Let $\Gamma$ be the graph of the parabola $y = x^2$ in the $xy$-plane. Let $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the map

$$ x \mapsto (x, x^2). $$

It is actually a diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\Gamma$. Let $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ be $3$ distinct points on $\Gamma$. The formula for the $3\times 3$ Vandermonde determinant then tells us that the area $A(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ of the triangle with vertices $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ is given by

$$ A(p_1, p_2, p_3) = \frac{1}{2}|x_2 - x_1| |x_3 - x_1| |x_3 - x_2|,$$

where $p_i = \gamma(x_i)$ for $1 \leq i \leq 3$.

The problem I propose is to find a geometric proof of the above formula for $A(p_1, p_2, p_3)$. It is a problem in $2$-dimensional Euclidean geometry, so there may be a nice geometric proof of it. Thoughts and/or comments are welcome!

Edit 1: Thanks for @Jean Marie for pointing out the link with another question, namely [Area of triangle inscribed in a parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750501/area-of-triangle-inscribed-in-a-parabola). The questions are definitely very closely related. I didn't think about using tangents actually, while the question there does, which is good, since it allows for more general parabolas such as for instance $y = a x^2$, where $a$ is not necessarily $1$. The reason why I think I should keep this post, is that the answers there at the time of writing do not provide a geometric proof. One proof uses calculus, and I think the other one uses a Vandermonde determinant.

I already know one proof using Vandermonde determinants, but I am still interested in a geometric proof. You see, I am interested in a more complex problem (the Atiyah problem on configurations), and having a geometric proof of the formula here may help, if it generalizes to rational normal curves instead of the $\gamma$ here. But I am trying to go step by step.

The next problem I would like to propose is actually an area inequality, closely related to this one, and which implies the $n = 3$ special case of the Atiyah-Sutcliffe problem on configurations of points. I have created a post for that problem for those who are interested: [A lower bound on an area of a triangle defined using $6$ distinct points on a parabola.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4337545/a-lower-bound-on-an-area-of-a-triangle-defined-using-6-distinct-points-on-a-pa)

Edit 2: Here is an approach I'd be interested in. In the other post Jean Marie linked to (Area of triangle inscribed in a parabola), they equate the area of a triangle inscribed in a parabola with twice the area of the triangle formed by the tangents to the parabola at the 3 vertices. I am convinced this is related to some kind of projective duality in the plane between points and lines, and this is the kind of algebro-geometric ideas I would like to see at play (as these would generalize to higher degree rational normal curves). So I propose the same problem as that other post (or the I guess equivalent formula I propose here, though I don't immediately see the equivalence) using ideas from classical algebraic geometry such as duality and rational normal curves.

Edit 3: I keep getting messages that the post [Area of triangle inscribed in a parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750501/area-of-triangle-inscribed-in-a-parabola) may answer my questions. The setup is pretty much the same, a triangle inscribed in a parabola, and in that post, they are also interested in the area of that triangle. The right-hand side in what they are trying to show in that post, namely that the area of such a triangle is twice the area of the triangle defined by the tangent lines to the parabola at the $3$ vertices of the triangle, is not very obviously equal to the right-hand side in the formula here. I mean, I am sure there is some nice argument for why the $2$ right-hand sides are equal, but it is not very obvious.

If you guys decide to close this post, it is fine with me, but I hope that at least @Intelligenti pauca will write a similar nice answer to that other post along similar geometric lines. That answer is nice and deserves to be somewhere on Math.SE!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Area of triangle inscribed in a parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750501/area-of-triangle-inscribed-in-a-parabola)

Comment: @JeanMarie, I edited my post. Thank you for bringing that post to my attention! Merci beaucoup!

Comment: This falls right out of [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula). It helps to use the "expanded" form $$\frac14\sqrt{-a^4-b^4-c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2}$$ which eliminates the square roots in Pythagorean representations of the sides. There's some slightly-messy algebra involved, but the final form tells us that we should expect nice factorization. There may be a more-direct geometric path. ... BTW, with $f$ the distance from focus to vertex, the general formula is $$8fA=|x_1-x_2||x_2-x_3||x_3-x_1|$$ which also has the benefit of dimensional consistency.

Comment: @Blue, yes I am sure it follows from Heron's formula, though it requires simplification of course. And thank you for your useful comment at the end. Yes you are right.

Comment: As you are looking for "higher understanding"; there is a connection with the theory of "**centro-affine geometry**" I have been working on in the past. Maybe, I will be able to find back documents I had on this question.

Comment: @JeanMarie, I would be really interested. Thank you. I also created a new post, which contains my next challenge/problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4337545/a-lower-bound-on-an-area-of-a-triangle-defined-using-6-distinct-points-on-a-pa.

Comment: For the moment, I have just found another adjective for this geometry "equi-affine" geometry. Here is a [document](http://thomas.lewiner.org/pdfs/parabolic_polygon_jmiv.pdf) hopefuly connected to your quest...  I have seen as well your next question.

Comment: Do you know the 2D theorem  giving by using a paraboloid the Voronoi tessellation and Delaunay triangulation by projecting convex hulls as described [here](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/Lifting.pdf) ? I wouldn't be surprized there is some connection with your issue...

Comment: @JeanMarie, thank you very much! I am not sure how relevant the first document is, but the theorem you have mentioned (linking Delaunay triangles and convex hulls using a hyperboloid) is very interesting and may have some connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h_k$ are the projections of $p_k$ onto $x$ axis, then we have:
$$
A(p_1,p_2,p_3)=A(h_1,h_3,p_3,p_1)-A(h_1,h_2,p_2,p_1)-A(h_2,h_3,p_3,p_2),
$$
where I assumed $x_1<x_2<x_3$ to avoid using absolute values.
The areas of the three trapezoids on the r.h.s. can be computed and the result is:
$$
A(p_1,p_2,p_3)=
-{1\over2}\big[(x_1^2+x_3^2)(x_1-x_3)+(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_2-x_1)
+(x_2^2+x_3^2)(x_3-x_2)\big],
$$
which is the same as the expression given in the question.

[image]

Comment: I love it. Geometric and simple! Thank you so much!

Comment: I have taken the liberty to add a graphical representation that helps to follow the computations.

Comment: @JeanMarie, may I ask which software you have used to generate this nice graph please? It reminds me of graphs you see in French Math textbooks for high school Math, when they get to pre-calculus ("analyse").

Comment: I have used Geogebra. You can do the same thing with Desmos. Both are free software.