# A formula for the area of a triangle defined using 6 distinct points on a parabola

Tags: geometry, inequality, area

(Note: I have heavily edited this post and I am now asking 1 main question using the same setup.)

Let $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the following smooth embedding
$$ \gamma(x) = (x, x^2).$$
The image of $\gamma$ is the parabola $y = x^2$. Let $x_{ij}$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq 3$ and $i \neq j$, be $6$ distinct real numbers. Let $p_{ij} = \gamma(x_{ij})$ (i.e. $p_{12} = \gamma(x_{12})$ and so on). So we now have $6$ distinct points (the $p_{ij}$s) on the parabola $y = x^2$. Actually we could have started with $6$ distinct points on $y = x^2$.

Let $l_1$ be the line joining $p_{12}$ and $p_{13}$, $l_2$ be the line joining $p_{23}$ and $p_{21}$ and $l_3$ be the line joining $p_{31}$ and $p_{32}$.

Let $p_1 = l_2 \cap l_3$, $p_2 = l_3 \cap l_1$ and $p_3 = l_1 \cap l_2$. Write $p_i = (x_i, y_i)$ for $1 \leq i \leq 3$. Let $A$ denote the signed area of the triangle with vertices $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$, in that order.

The problem can now be formulated. Show that

$$ \frac{4A^2}{\prod_{i < j} (x_j - x_i)} = (x_{21} - x_{31}) \, (x_{12} - x_{32}) \, (x_{13} - x_{23}) + \prod_{i < j}(x_{ij} - x_{ji}).$$

Note that the problems mentioned in my previous post [Is there a geometric proof of this geometric interpretation of the Vandermonde determinant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336970/is-there-a-geometric-proof-of-this-geometric-interpretation-of-the-vandermonde-d) as well as the related post [Area of triangle inscribed in a parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750501/area-of-triangle-inscribed-in-a-parabola) both essentially correspond to a limiting case of the above, where you have $3$ distinct points on the parabola, say $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ and $p_{ij} = p_j$ for all $1 \leq i, j \leq 3$ and $i \neq j$. In other words, you have $p_{12} = p_{32}$, $p_{13} = p_{23}$ and $p_{21} = p_{31}$. In this degenerate case, the first term on the RHS of the formula vanishes, and the formula then amounts to
$$ 2|A| = \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq 3} |x_j - x_i|. $$

So the formula in this post can be seen as a generalization of this formula for the area of a triangle inscribed in a parabola.

Note: I tried to be careful with signs and I will double check the main formula, but there could be a sign mistake somewhere.